# Обновить 2 div'a через ajax

Tags: ajax

Сильно не пинайте, ибо почти не знаю AJAX. Но нужно обновить 2 дива. Есть кнопки голосования (+ и -). Над "+" - количество плюсов, над "-" тоже. Между ними графически отображается картинка (градиент зависит от итога плюсов и минусов).  Он перерисовывается заново. Есть итог: кол-во плюсов -(минус) кол-во минусов. Он в одном диве вместе с "картинкой". Этот див я и обновляю. А над кнопкой + или - просто яваскриптом получаю значение дива, прибавляю или отнимаю 1 и заменяю по событию onclick. НО! Если кто-то другой проголосует за этот пост, а потом текущий пользователь, то получается - с сервера придут актуальные данные, а то, что я изменяю просто яваскриптом (+1 или -1) уже неатуально. Вот и нужно изменить 2 дива: количество над кнопкой и итог в разных дивах.

Пояснение:

до [image: Pic2]

после [image: Pic2]

пояснение [image: Pic2]

Див 2 обновляется через аякс, т.е. в ответе приходит новое число (итог), над кнопками изменяю следующим кодом яваскрипта:

```
    //получаем див кнопки 'плюс' и 'минус'
    var b_plus = document.getElementById('vote_plus_'+id_review);
    var b_minus = document.getElementById('vote_minus_'+id_review);
    if(b_plus && b_minus)
    {
        if(!b_plus.disabled)
        {
            b_minus.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
            var counter = document.getElementById('counter_minuses_'+id_review);
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
        //иначе значит 'плюс' выключена и юзер хочет отменить голос
        //отнимаем от счетчика плюсов -1
        else
        {
            var counter = document.getElementById('counter_pluses_'+id_review);
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) - 1;
        }
        //нажата кнопка 'минус' значит выключаем ее
        b_plus.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Например, кто-то нажал 5 минусов. Текущий юзер плюсует. Над кнопкой "+" будет 1, под кнопкой "-" будет 0, а итог придет -4 ((

Comment: > Сильно не пинайте...

Только слегка )) Очень путаное пояснение. Не плохо было бы увидеть структуру этого блока и уточнить суть задачи. Пока я для себя понял примерно так: нажали на "плюс/минус" > ajax-запрос на обновление данных в БД/файле > возвращаем итоговый результат > выводим данные с "перерисовкой" графической части показателя.

Comment: @Deonis, фух, обновил. Добавление картинок здесь - это нечто.  
П.С. Почему нельзя было прикрутить сюда какой-нибудь нормальный "комментатор". Форматирование - бред...

Comment: Если у вас два числа хранятся в базе для плюсов и для минусов, следовательно возвращайте аяксом эти два числа. Итог считайте в js. Зачем возвращаете итог? он не содержит полной информации о голосовании...

ЗЫ комментатор тут нормальный, просто всем лень читать документацию. как обычно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а не подскажете куда копать, чтоб вернуть сервером значения, а яваскриптом распределить? Не понимаю по какому событию запустить яваскрипт. Насколько я понимаю, возможен алгоритм: 1. нажата кнопка, данные отправлены 2. на сервере обработались, отправлен ответ (2 значения) 3. пришли и изменили 3 дива. Вот как 3-ий пункт сделать не знаю((  
Зы. Документацию раньше читал. Основную. А тут пришлось дойти до "первоисточника", т.е. до документации с сайта разработчика этого комментатора)

Comment: @Андрей Бакша Да, все верно. Просто аяксом можно вернуть не одно число, например, а json объект, например: ``{plus:5, minus:1}``. Дальше работаете с этим объектом. Увеличивать значения по имеющимся на странице (то что у вас в дивах прописано) не нужно. Раз с сервера приходят данные значит нужно вносить изменения в соответствии с ними. См. ответ @Deonis, все довольно прозрачно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Посмотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/TakK2/2/) (примитивно, но главное суть).

HTML

```
<div class="rating">
    <div class="block">
        <span class="but plus">+</span>
        <span class="cnt">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="block middle">
        <div class="graph"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <span class="but minus">-</span>
        <span class="cnt">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rating {
    max-width: 300px;
}
.block {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.middle {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.but {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.graph {
    height: 20px;
    width: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

JS

```
var button = $('.but');
var counters = $('.rating .cnt');
var graph = $('.graph');
var blockW = $('.rating').width();
var unit = 1;
var votes = 0;
var allPlus = 0;
var allMinus = 0;
var color;
function _recalc(p,m){
    counters.eq(0).text(p);
    counters.eq(1).text(m);
    votes = - m + p;
    if(votes){
        var percent = blockW / votes * p;
        if(percent > (blockW - blockW / 3)) {
            color = '#060';
        } else if(percent <= (blockW - blockW / 3) && percent >= (blockW / 3)) {
            color = '#FF8000';
        } else if(percent < (blockW / 3)) {
            color = '#F00';
        }
        $('.graph').animate({
            backgroundColor: color,
            width: percent + 'px'
        });
    }
}

button.click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('minus')){
        unit = -1;
        allMinus--;
    } else {
        allPlus++;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/', // путь к обработчику
        data: {add_unit: unit}, // отправляем или "1", или "-1", которые апдейтим в БД
        success: function(data){
            // Как бы ответ приехал...
            // Предположим, что дата содержит кол-во "плюсов" и "минусов" из БД
            // отправляем их в функцию на вывод данных
            _recalc(allPlus, allMinus);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Вместо данных из БД использовал обычные переменные (на jsFiddle с БД не поработаешь). Если что-то не будет понятно - спрашивайте.

Comment: Без анимации не обходится ни один ответ! Красавчик :)

Comment: Жопаделать... В детстве не наигрался, так на старости лет отрываюсь ))

Comment: @Deonis, я Вам очень благодарен за такую помощь. Правда не ожидал) Хотелось бы Вам пожать руку. Еще раз спасибо огромное.
П.С. Всем тоже очень благодарен за любую помощь) Отличный форум.